# Angular SPA - does not show items sent from server via SignalR when reloading component

Tags: angular, signalr

I am quite new to Angular 8 + SignalR combination and I have run into a very annoying issue. I have a component that displays items sent via `SignalR` without any problem, but when I navigate to a different component and back to the first one, the items are not displayed, however, I can see the items in the log bubbled up via `SignalR` again, but the `UI` does not update.

The component called listings, which on `ngOnInit()` opens the `Signal` connection, calls the server and creates the bindings to handle changes in the `SignalR` hub on the server.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.signalRService.connection();
this.startHttpRequest();
this.signalRService.hubConnection.on('ListingResponse', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.ListingsData = data;
});

this.signalRService.hubConnection.on('ListingAdded', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.ListingsData.push(data);
});
}

private startHttpRequest = () => {
this.http.get('/LongDistListing/')
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

This works fine. This component is added to the home component and loads the items when the app starts without any problem, however when I click on another link in the nav menu than back, the `UI` does not display the listings. I can see the console logs and the listings have been sent back via `SignalR`.

The listing component `ngOnInit()` works, server side works, I can see the listings are sent back via `SignalR`, but I have no idea where the problem is..

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent }
]),
```

Anything to do with `SPA` routing?

Comment: I think you should create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example since it doesn't make any sense that this doesn't work. That way it will be easier for people to test and solve your issue...

Comment: How do you create a Angular, SignalR example on stackblitz? Is it possible? I am sorry if my question gives you the impression of a "this doesn't work" type. Unfortunately, I have no idea where the problem lies, but I feel like it is more of an SignalR issue

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out why it was not working. As you can see on `ngOnInit()` first I connect to the `SignalR hub`, then call the controller which will eventually bubble up the result via `SignalR` and the last two methods will be the `SignalR` "listeners".

First issue, you have the setup up the "listeners" before you call the controller, but the main issue was that on `this.signalRService.connection();` it took longer to connect to the `SignalR hub` therefore the listings have already been pushed back from the server much before the FE was connected to the `SignalR hub` on the server and was able to subscribe to any changes.

How to solve it: You have to make sure to wait for the connection to finish first.

Also this is a quite annyoing issue, as it works perfectly on page load, however when you load a different component in `Angular` and go back to the one with the `SignalR` listing, it will NOT work